# Chronicle-queue replication error: Received a handler for host ID: 1, my host ID is: 2 this is probably a configuration error

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I am currently testing and learning chronicle-queue enterprise replication using the documentation below:

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/ea/docs/replication.adoc#the-mechanics-of-chronicle-queue-replication

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/ea/docs/queue-replication-message-protocol-overview.adoc#sinkreplicationhandler

However, I am getting the error below:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**: Received a handler for host ID: 1, my host ID is: 2 this is probably a configuration error.

My replication configuration is as below, what am I missing? Below is my replication configuration.

```
!ChronicleQueueReplicationCfg {
  eventId: "",
  serviceId: "",
  replicaSets: {
    global: !!set [
      host1,
      host2
    ]
  },
  allowSinkToSource: false,
  context: {
    networkContextFactory: !software.chronicle.enterprise.queue.replication.QueueClusterNetworkContext$Factory INSTANCE,
    heartbeatTimeoutMs: 500000,
    heartbeatIntervalMs: 300000,
    pauserSupplier: !PauserMode busy,
    replicationPauserSupplier: !!null "",
    affinityCPU: !!null "",
    wireType: BINARY_LIGHT,
    localIdentifier: 1,
    localName: host1,
    serverThreadingStrategy: SINGLE_THREADED,
    retryInterval: 1000,
    procPrefix: !!null "",
    baseSourcePath: source,
    baseSinkPath: replica,
    backfillTimeoutListener: !software.chronicle.enterprise.queue.replication.NoopBackfillListener INSTANCE,
    tcpBias: !!null ""
  },
  hosts: {
    host1: { hostId: 1, tcpBufferSize: 0, connectUri: "localhost:5001" },
    host2: { hostId: 2, tcpBufferSize: 0, connectUri: "localhost:5002" }
  },
  queues: {
    queue1: {
      name: queue1,
      path: queue1,
      replicaSets: [
        global
      ],
      masterId: 1,
      waitForSinks: 0
    }
  }
}
```

chronicle-queue-enterprise-all-2.23ea26

Comment: Hi, It might be best if email a support issue so we can share code to reproduce this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey what generally causes that error?  According to the documentation, the UberHandlers  "are serialized locally, and then sent to the remote host using TCP/IP".  I am attempting to test it out on the same windows host just different ports but this should not be a problem, right?

Comment: Correct, this is tested between 2 and 3 nodes running on the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question based on the feedback given. The issue was caused by me passing the same instance of the ChronicleQueueReplicationCfg to each side of the replication when I was creating the ReplicatedQueue objects. I had missed that the ChronicleQueueReplicationCfg objects were stateful when the replication starts up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as an answer since I need to share some configuration.

Your configuration seems correct, however, there might be an issue with the code that is utilizing it. Within `chronicle-queue-enterprise` there are many tests that showcase how to use the replication features.

The simplest one you can apply your configuration to is called `ReplicationTest.shouldReplicate`. This test simply writes two messages to the `source` and verifies that it can read the same messages from the `sink` (which would mean that replication worked).

I applied your configuration in this test with minor changes.

```
!ChronicleQueueReplicationCfg {
  eventId: "",
  serviceId: "",
  replicaSets: {
    global: !!set [
      host1,
      host2
    ]
  },
  allowSinkToSource: false,
  context: {
    networkContextFactory: !software.chronicle.enterprise.queue.replication.QueueClusterNetworkContext$Factory INSTANCE,
    heartbeatTimeoutMs: 500000,
    heartbeatIntervalMs: 300000,
    pauserSupplier: !PauserMode busy,
    replicationPauserSupplier: !!null "",
    affinityCPU: !!null "",
    wireType: BINARY_LIGHT,
    localIdentifier: 1,
    localName: host1,
    serverThreadingStrategy: SINGLE_THREADED,
    retryInterval: 1000,
    procPrefix: !!null "",
    baseSourcePath: "replica/source",
    baseSinkPath: "replica/sink$hostId",
    backfillTimeoutListener: !software.chronicle.enterprise.queue.replication.NoopBackfillListener INSTANCE,
    tcpBias: !!null ""
  },
  hosts: {
    host1: { hostId: 1, tcpBufferSize: 0, connectUri: host.port1 },
    host2: { hostId: 2, tcpBufferSize: 0, connectUri: host.port2 }
  },
  queues: {
    queue1: {
      name: queue1,
      path: queue1,
      acknowledge: true,
      allowUnknownSinks: true,
      replicaSets: [
        global
      ],
      masterId: 1,
      waitForSinks: 0
    }
  }
}
```

I could not replicate the same `IllegalArgumentException` you were having, please share the code that uses your configuration and I'm sure we will find out what's wrong and update this answer.